# New command for subscript with text

Tags: macros

I am typing a file where I often have to write `$T_{\text{area}}$`. But the command for adding text in a subscript is quite long when I have to write it all the time. Do anyone have any tips on a newcommand that could simplify this, for example where I can type T_area and that gives me the correct format?

I tried to use

```
\newcommand{T_area}{S_{\text{area}}}
```

but it does not work. Also It would be nice to generalize it for all texts, not ony "area".

Comment: You can't (easily) use an underscore in a macro name; just letters. Use `\Tarea` and it'll work. (Notice the backslash).

Comment: newcommand needs a command starting `\ ` so  `\newcommand\Sarea{S_{\mathrm{area}}}`

Comment: Unrelated, as David show don't use `\text`  for this, it does not do what you think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The instruction

```
\newcommand{T_area}{S_{\text{area}}}
```

is faulty for two separate reasons. First, TeX macros should generally start with a `\` (backslash) character. (Well, there is the `\csname ... \endcsname` possibility; however, that's clearly not what you're concerned with.) Second, TeX control sequences should consist of either one or more lowercase and uppercase alphabetical letters (also known as `a` to `z` and `A` to `Z`...) or *exactly one* non-letter character. Examples of non-letter control sequences are `\,`, `\!`, `\_`, `\$`, `\%`, `\\`, etc.

Building on these two insights, the alternative definition

```
\newcommand{\Tarea}{S_{\text{area}}}
```

is valid -- but only from a purely syntactical point of view. As the comments posted below the query have already pointed out, the output of the `\text` macro is not as robust as you may think it is. Try executing `$\Tarea$ \textit{$\Tarea$} \textsc{$\Tarea$} \texttt{$\Tarea$}` and be prepared to be surprised. If you want the subscript material to be typeset exclusively in the upright shape of the document's main text font, give

```
\newcommand\TareaX{S_{\textnormal{area}}}
```

a try. Of course, you are entirely free to choose a different macro name.

> Also It would be nice to generalize it for all texts, not ony "area".

Using some unavoidable LaTeX jargon, this objective may be achieved by specifying that `\TareaX` takes an optional argument with default value `area`:

```
\newcommand\TareaX[1][area]{S_{\textnormal{#1}}}
```

A final remark: Since the TeX-special character `_` occurs in the definitions of the macros `\Tarea` and `\TareaX`, TeX will issue a (possibly mysterious) warning or error message if these macros are *not* used while inside math mode.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \text macro

\newcommand\Tarea{S_{\text{area}}} % problematic
\newcommand\TareaX[1][area]{S_{\textnormal{#1}}} % fine

\begin{document}
$\Tarea$ \textit{$\Tarea$} \textsc{$\Tarea$} \texttt{$\Tarea$} --- not good

$\TareaX$ \textit{$\TareaX$} \textsc{$\TareaX[volume]$} \texttt{$\TareaX[length]$} --- good
\end{document}
```

Comment: Extra +1 for the `\text` explanation